# JSON to multidimensional php array in wordpress

Tags: php, arrays, json, rest, multidimensional-array

I'm using a wordpress plugin to handle multiple addresses in Woocommerce, and I'm trying to import a JSON array of addresses via REST into wordpress, and would like it in the right format for wp. I pass in this data as a variable called meta_value, via PostMan. The correct format of data needed by the plugin looks like this:

```
a:3:{i:0;a:9:{s:19:"shipping_first_name";s:5:"David";s:18:"shipping_last_name";
s:5:"Smith";s:16:"shipping_company";s:9:"Company A";s:16:"shipping_country";s:2:
"GB";s:18:"shipping_address_1";s:10:"House Name";s:18:"shipping_address_2";s:14:
"50 Street Name";s:13:"shipping_city";s:7:"Salford";s:14:"shipping_state";s:18:
"GREATER MANCHESTER";s:17:"shipping_postcode";s:7:"M20 2GL";}i:1;a:9:{s:19:
"shipping_first_name";s:4:"John";s:18:"shipping_last_name";s:5:"Smith";s:16:
"shipping_company";s:9:"Company B";s:16:"shipping_country";s:2:"GB";s:18:
"shipping_address_1";s:17:"26 Arcadia Avenue";s:18:"shipping_address_2";s:10:
"Kensington";s:13:"shipping_city";s:9:"Liverpool";s:14:"shipping_state";s:10:
"Merseyside";s:17:"shipping_postcode";s:7:"L14 3AD";}i:2;a:9:{s:19:
"shipping_first_name";s:4:"Jack";s:18:
"shipping_last_name";s:5:"Smith";s:16:
"shipping_company";s:9:"Company C";s:16:"shipping_country";s:2:"DZ";s:18:
"shipping_address_1";s:14:"23 Some Street";s:18:"shipping_address_2";s:9:
"Somewhere";s:13:"shipping_city";s:7:"Salford";s:14:"shipping_state";s:18:
"GREATER MANCHESTER";s:17:"shipping_postcode";s:7:"M40 3BS";}}
```

This code I wrote to do this seems to work when I use online testers / validators:

```
function object2array($object) { return json_decode(json_encode($object),true); }

$testcontent ='[
{
"shipping_first_name":"David",
"shipping_last_name":"Smith",
"shipping_company":"Company A",

"shipping_country":"GB",
"shipping_address_1":"House Name",
"shipping_address_2":"50 Street Name",
"shipping_city":"Salford",
"shipping_state":"GREATER MANCHESTER",
"shipping_postcode":"M20 2GL"
},
{
"shipping_first_name":"John",
"shipping_last_name":"Smith",
"shipping_company":"Company B",
"shipping_country":"GB",
"shipping_address_1":"26 Arcadia Avenue",
"shipping_address_2":"Kensington",
"shipping_city":"Liverpool",
"shipping_state":"Merseyside",
"shipping_postcode":"L14 3AD"
},
{
"shipping_first_name":"Jack",
"shipping_last_name":"Smith",
"shipping_company":"Company C",
"shipping_country":"DZ",
"shipping_address_1":"23 Some Street",
"shipping_address_2":"Somewhere",
"shipping_city":"Salford",
"shipping_state":"GREATER MANCHESTER",
"shipping_postcode":"M40 3BS"
}
]';

$json = serialize(object2array(json_decode($testcontent, true)));
$print_r($json);
```

But when I place it into the code of the plugin, it just doesn't want to play ball. I get all sorts of different formats, such as it combining the three arrays of 9 strings each into one larger array of 27 strings.

I've tried all sorts of combinations involving serialize, json_decode, json_encode and more, I'm hoping someone would be willing to help me learn what's going on and where I got it wrong...

The plugin code is here (I had to include the function within theirs as I couldn't get another public function to work for some odd reason):

```
public function update_user_meta() {
function object2array($object) { return json_decode(json_encode($object),true); }
  global $json_api;

 if (!$json_api->query->cookie) {
        $json_api->error("You must include a 'cookie' var in your request. Use the `generate_auth_cookie` method.");
    }

    $user_id = wp_validate_auth_cookie($json_api->query->cookie, 'logged_in');

if (!$user_id)  $json_api->error("Invalid cookie. Use the `generate_auth_cookie` method.");

   if (!$json_api->query->meta_key) $json_api->error("You must include a 'meta_key' variable in your request.");

    else $meta_key = $json_api->query->meta_key;

   if (!$json_api->query->meta_value) {
        $json_api->error("You must include a 'meta_value' var in your request. You may provide multiple values separated by comma for 'meta_value' var.");
        }
        else $meta_value = $json_api->query->meta_value;

$json = serialize(object2array(json_decode($meta_value)));

$data['updated'] = update_user_meta(  $user_id, $meta_key, $json);

       return $data;

  }
```

Thanks for looking - I'm still very new to php and REST, so I've struggled along to get to this point and now I need some help !!

Comment: That very first dump you show at the top of the page is just serialized, it's not json encoded. So if that `$testcontent` is what you're constructing, then just make it using proper arrays and serialize it, don't make a JSON string.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. The first dump is an example of how I need the data to be stored, I know it's serialized, which is why I was trying to serialize the data in the bottom code ($json)...

the data in $testcontent is an example of the JSON data that's being provided to me via an ERP system that I need to get in to the database via REST into the correct format... is there a better way of doing it then ? Sorry I'm new to all this...